# Model object becomes null. Is there any change required for ModelDriven interface when upgrading from struts 2.3.35 to 2.5.26?

Tags: struts2, model-driven

Does migration from 2.3.35 to 2.5.26 needs any change to use ModelDriven interface?

I have an action class that implements ModelDriven interface. It was working fine with struts 2.3.35. After upgrading to struts 2.5.26, **the model becomes null when we try to fetch it**.

This is the reference code:

```
public class MyAction extends MyBaseAction
        implements ModelDriven<BulkModel>, ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware {

private BulkModel bulkModel;

public MyAction getModel() {
       if(null==bulkModel){
         bulkModel = new BulkModel();
       }
        return bulkModel;
}

public myMethod(){
System.out.println(bulkModel.getName());
}

}
```

I use both these interceptors for my action:

```
            <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven" />
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
```

Comment: I use both these interceptors for my action:<interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven" />
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />

Comment: `scopedModelDriven` will not do anything here since the action doesn't implement `ScopedModelDriven`. Is `getModel` being called?

Comment: getModel is getting called. I can see the bulkModel always getting null in the getModel() call

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect it to be not null?